# Babel compile error: Cannot find module core-js/library/fn/get-iterator

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, node-modules

This is my directory structure:

```
├───demo
│   ├───entry
│   │   ├───index.js
│   │   ├───tap.js
│   │   └───util.js
│   ├───node_modules
│   ├───index.html
│   ├───package.json
│   └───webpack.config.js
├───src
│   ├───tap.js
│   └───util.js
├───index.js
└───package.json
```

In `demo/entry/index.js` I have

```
import tap from '../../src/tap';
```

When compiling this, babel throws error

```
ERROR in ../src/tap.js
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'core-js/library/fn/get-iterator'
```

But it works if I import like this

```
import tap from './tap';
```

The file `./tap.js` and `../../src/tap` are the same.

Is the problem `node_modules`? Because in `demo` directory, the babel and anything else is in `node_modules`, so I can `import` any file I like. But `src/tap.js` has no such parent or sibling directory like `node_modules`, so it will trigger this error.

Comment: The only time this happened to me, some folders disappeared from node_modules/core-js/library. I had to delete and re-install core-js.

Comment: you sure that `tab.js` does not have a `import ...get-iterator` somewhere it looks to me that you are doing it right, tab.js is now imported, but then you have to deal with it's imports.

Comment: any progress on this error? I got the same error while running react tutorial. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/index.htm

Answer (score 4):

Try to install babel-loader and babel-core as dev-dependency:

```
npm install babel-core babel-loader --save-dev
```

Also you need to update your `.babelrc`

```
{ 
    "presets" : ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

It works good for me. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you did not install core-js.
I used to meet this problem.

- First, delete your node_modules directory contents
- Second, execute `yarn install` if you had installed yarn
- Third, check your webpack version and babel-loader version, webpack 1.x can must be related to babel-loader 6.x

Comment: this `delete and reinstall all` works for me. But why?

Answer (score 2):

I just installed core-js and it worked.

Comment: reinstall core-js was enough for me too, I don't understand downvotes

Answer (score 2):

Updating to node version `11.10.0` (Current Version) worked for me.